# Set Outer Border of Apache POI XWPFTable table?

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I need to set the outer border of a Apache POI XWPFTable table. I know the below command set insade border, but do not find way for setting outer border.

```
table.setInsideHBorder( XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "FF0000");
```

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11):

I find it:

```
CTTblPr tblpro = table.getCTTbl().getTblPr();

CTTblBorders borders = tblpro.addNewTblBorders();
borders.addNewBottom().setVal(STBorder.SINGLE); 
borders.addNewLeft().setVal(STBorder.SINGLE);
borders.addNewRight().setVal(STBorder.SINGLE);
borders.addNewTop().setVal(STBorder.SINGLE);
//also inner borders
borders.addNewInsideH().setVal(STBorder.SINGLE);
borders.addNewInsideV().setVal(STBorder.SINGLE);
```

Comment: STBorder.SINGLE didn't work for me, I used STBorder.NONE instead

Comment: its helped me for making the borderless table with NONE, thank you

Answer (score 2):

To remove all borders from table:

```
tab.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getLeft().setVal(STBorder.NONE);    
tab.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getRight().setVal(STBorder.NONE);    
tab.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getTop().setVal(STBorder.NONE);    
tab.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().getBottom().setVal(STBorder.NONE);
```

Comment: This works, but doesn't remove the inner borders - for this you also need to add:
...Borders().getInsideH().setVal(STBorder.NONE);
...Borders().getInsideV().setVal(STBorder.NONE);

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is it not what you exactly looking for, but it you what to copy border style from one table to another you can use this method:

```
private void copyTableBorderStyle(XWPFTable table, XWPFTable newTable) {
    newTable.setInsideHBorder(table.getInsideHBorderType(), table.getInsideHBorderSize(), table.getInsideHBorderSpace(), table.getInsideHBorderColor());
    newTable.setInsideVBorder(table.getInsideVBorderType(), table.getInsideVBorderSize(), table.getInsideVBorderSpace(), table.getInsideVBorderColor());
    newTable.getCTTbl().setTblPr(table.getCTTbl().getTblPr()); 
    newTable.getCTTbl().setTblGrid(table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid());
}
```

But for your question if you what to change outer border you need to get [org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTbl](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTTbl.java) property and configure it:

```
CTTbl cttbl = table.getCTTbl();
```