# Table borders are not copied with apache poi, ms-word

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I found a way to copy a table from one document to another, but the outer and inner borders of the table are not copied. I use `apache poi`. Сould you help me?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oTPU.jpg)

```java
public static void copyTable(XWPFDocument input_doc,XWPFDocument output_doc,
            int table_index_input, int table_index_output) {

XWPFTable template_table = input_doc.getTables().get(table_index_input);

CTTbl ctTbl = CTTbl.Factory.newInstance(); // Create a new CTTbl for the new table
ctTbl.set(template_table.getCTTbl()); // Copy the template table's CTTbl
XWPFTable new_table = new XWPFTable(ctTbl, output_doc); // Create a new table using the CTTbl upon

new_table.setInsideHBorder(template_table.getInsideHBorderType(), template_table.getInsideHBorderSize(), template_table.getInsideHBorderSpace(), template_table.getInsideHBorderColor());
new_table.setInsideVBorder(template_table.getInsideVBorderType(), template_table.getInsideVBorderSize(), template_table.getInsideVBorderSpace(), template_table.getInsideVBorderColor());
new_table.getCTTbl().setTblPr(template_table.getCTTbl().getTblPr()); 
new_table.getCTTbl().setTblGrid(template_table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid());

output_doc.createParagraph();
output_doc.createTable();// Create a empty table in the document
output_doc.setTable(table_index_output, new_table);  // Replace the empty table to table2
}
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34093304/7644018) help?

Comment: @PaulT. it didn’t help me, or I didn’t use it correctly

Comment: Maybe table styles of your `input_doc` are not set directly in table's  `XML`. Instead maybe they are set in `/word/styles.xml`. So `/word/styles.xml` partially would must be copied too. Not really practicable. I have given up the aproach to copy parts from template to target. Instead open template, change that and then save changed template as target.